# Using Google Apps and Amazon SES together on Amazon Route 53 DNS settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-ses

Currently, I am using Google Apps to receive an email to my verified domain address. 
Now, I would like to use Amazon SES as well to use S3 action on email route to my specific email address on my verified domain.
So, lets say my domain address is **"sample.com"**. I was using only Google Apps before so my DNS settings MX records was :

```
5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

Then I add the line :

```
20 inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
```

to my "sample.com" DNS settings MX record set to use Amazon SES as well.

And the line :

```
"some_relevant_text="
```

to *_amazonses.sample.com.* TXT record set.

Then I created receive rule for my email address, lets say my specific email address is **"sample-email@sample.com"**.

I did follow every single procedure on tutorial.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started.html

But unfortunately, it does not work. And I could not figure out why.

If you have had this kind of issues before and can help me to figure out the reason, it will be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you give it time to Propagate the DNS changes?

Comment: I think so, I have the same issue nearly for 4-5 days. Do you think it is enough?

Comment: Is your domain showing verified in the SES console

Comment: yes, it's verified

Comment: When someone sends you an email, do you want it to go to google or amazon?

Comment: For my specific "sample-email@sample.com" email I want it go to Amazon SES but for other ones I want them go to Google.

Comment: There is no way to tell that to sending server. You have to pick one, and perhaps find the way to configure some specific forwarding (which might even be impossible on public email provider like gmail).

Comment: So, I can not specify any email address route to Amazon SES? @DusanBajic

Comment: Not by using DNS only. What might work for you is 1) have emails sent to google as before (remove newly added MX record) 2) create AWS SES MX/TXT entry for a new subdomain ( for example `ses.sample.com`) 2) configure google to forward all mails received for "sample-email@sample.com" to "sample-email@aws.sample.com"

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks @DusanBajic I will try the same method.

Comment: Confirming that @DusanBajic solution works. You should post it as an answer.